# How do I get the appointments from an Exchange calendar?

Tags: com, outlook, exchangewebservices

How do I fetch appointments from another user's Microsoft Exchange calendar in a script?

Comment: This is to create an appointment, but is it the kind of thing you were thinking of? http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Create_Outlook_Appointment,_Shared_Folder

Comment: I don't know exactly which API I need, but my first choice would be to use Python's win32com module.

Answer (score 0):

MAPI as in "Extended MAPI"? It can only be accessed in C++ or Delphi.
Do you mean CDO 1.21? Or Outlook Object Model? Or Redemption?

Answer (score 0):

I used `GetUserAvailability` via `SOAP` and the Python `suds` module. It returns free/busy information for any number of users in a single call at the granularity you request. This is the same information behind Outlook's scheduling assistant and was just what I needed.